# ng-view not rendering in cshtml

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-routing, ng-view

I have an inquiry about the failure of ng-view to render a partial view in a cshtml page in a hybrid angularjs and asp.net mvc application. I have seen this work before, but cannot locate the cause of my failure.

the general scenario is to present a cshtml page which accepts input for a search and present the results on the same page while retaining the input text box for subsequent searches.

the cshtml page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Search</title>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-app="searchModule" data-ng-controller="searchController">
        <br />

        <form id="search-form" data-ng-submit="searchProperty()" >
            <label for="search" data-icon="&#xe618;">
                <input id="search" type="search" data-ng-model="searchTerm" placeholder="enter title of property to find" style="width:800px; max-width:800px" />
            </label>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div ng-view="">

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/searchBundle")
}
```

the angularjs controller responding to the search string submission:

```
searchModule.controller('searchController', function ($scope, $location, $window) {

    var url = "/search/results/";

    $scope.searchProperty = function()
    {
        //$location.path(url + $scope.searchTerm);
        window.location = url + $scope.searchTerm;
    }

});

searchModule.controller('searchResultsController', function($scope, $routeParams) {

    $scope.searchTerm = 'test';
    $scope.properties = [];
    $scope.properties.push( {"id" : "1", "title": "property"});
});
```

the angularjs router which should handle the injection into the cshtml:

```
var searchModule = angular.module('searchModule', ['ngRoute']);

searchModule.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/search/results/:searchterm',
            {
                templateUrl: function (params) { return '/search/results/' + params.searchterm; },
                controller: 'searchResultsController',  //angularjs controller; the templateUrl is an mvc reference.
            })
    //.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

the relevant section of the mvc controller:

```
   public class SearchController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Search
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Search/Results/"title"
        [Route("Search/Results/{SearchTerm}")]
        public ActionResult Results(string SearchTerm)
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

finally, the cshtml partial view rendering the search results. I expected this to be injected into the index.cshtml, but is actually rendered on a new page.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search Results";
}
<div>
    <br />
    <h3 class="keyword" data-ng-show="searchTerm != null">Search: {{searchTerm}}</h3>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="property in properties">
                <td>{{property.id}}</td>
                <td>{{property.title}}</td>
                <td><a data-ng-href="/details/{{property.id}}" data-icon="&#x2192;"></a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

the following url appears when landing on the search box page:
http://localhost:5240/Search

the following url appears after the submission on a blank page except for the bad angularjs markup which can't find the desired scope.

http://localhost:5240/search/results/333

these are both good and desirable.
I am trying to avoid having the dreaded # appear in the url.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to lack of recognizing the true root of the navigation tree. 
When I changed the navigation url as follows, the application worked as desired.

```
var url = "/search/#/results";   //good url
var url = "/search/results/";    //bad url
```

the key was that the search box page is navigated to from a main page, and is part of a spa farm, so extra attention is needed for managing navigation trees.

I am still unhappy with the hash in the url, but will address that matter as a separate query when I undertake to better understand $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);